# There is a way to loop throught nested arrays like Matrioska, added dynamically?

Tags: arrays, angular, nested

I'm trying to declare a function into my Angular typescript class that could help me to loop throught nested arrays that are added dynamically because my template show a custom Kendo grid so I have this problem. I need to loop throught a type of Matrioska that everytime I add a grouping by the name column automatically inside the array inside the first generic array there is a second array and go on.

The structure is like this:

array:[

```
   obj1:{
    
        array:[
              

              obj:{

                   --the information that I want--
                    
                   }

              ]

   }
   obj2:{
    
        array:[
              

              obj:{

                   --the information that I want--
                    
                   }

              ]

   }
   obj3:{
    
        array:[
              

              obj:{

                   --the information that I want--
                    
                   }

              ]

        }
   ..............
   AND SO ON
```

]

I could use a recorsive method?

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
for(let first of response) { -> in array
  console.log(first) -> gives obj1.
  for(let second of first.array) { -> in array1
    console.log(second) -> gives obj.
  }
}
```